# What is the difference between a deterministic and randomised consensus protocol?

Tags: distributed-computing, blockchain, deterministic, non-deterministic, consensus

I have read that in order for some distributed systems to counter the FLP impossibility result, they change from a deterministic consensus protocol to a randomised consensus protocol, which gives a probabilistic approach to the system. Can anyone clarify this and the definitions for each

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to your question in the following papers:

- Another Advantage of Free Choice: Completely Asynchronous Agreement Protocols, PODC 1983
- The correctness proof of Ben-Or’s randomized consensus algorithm, Distributed Computing 2012